# Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason for pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I'm having trouble connecting to my sql express database from python on windows. I have mix mode authentication. I think the problem is from the hostname..

This is the command:

```
conn = pymssql.connect('(local)\SQLEXPRESS', 'user', 'password', 'db')
```

This is the error:

```
pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
```

Comment: Have the same issue. Not reproducible every time but happens 3 out of 4 times. Very annoying. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work, so I used adodbapi instead